# Entity framework unit testing with sqlite

Tags: unit-testing, sqlite, frameworks, entity

Is it possible to unit test Entity Framework v2 repositories with SqLite? Is this only possible if my entities are plain Poco and not automatically generated by Entity Framework?

I've generated a entity model from SqlServer and in the generated .edmx file i found this in section SSDL content: Provider="System.Data.SqlClient". Correct me if I am wrong, but shouldnt that be System.Data.SQLite in order to work with sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its only possible if two entity models are created (one for each provider) and then make both object contexts implement the same interface.

Its not worth the effort to manage two entity models.

I hope this get fixed in Entity Framework Ver 3.